# Why is my Miranda not coming to full pitchers and it has brown spots?

Tags: houseplants, leaves, plant-recommendations, fertilizer

I have a Miranda Nepenthes and I've had it for about 8 months or so. It is growing like crazy but I haven't had a pitcher to get to full maturity since it came in the mail. It starts to grow pitchers but they die before they get big. It has a beautiful bloom, however. Now, the older newer leaves and the older leaves are getting some brown spots and holes on and in the leaves. I have moved it to get morning sun and but that didn't work then I moved to get evening sun and that didn't work either. My house is pretty well lit so I think its getting enough light along with sitting in the window. It's about 3 foot tall and some of the new leaves are curling. I keep it wet but I have never fertilized it. I'm not sure about the humidity but I do have one of those heating pad things for plants and I was thinking about using it to help with humidity. Would that help? Please help me I don't want to lose my plant.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EXqZ.jpg